# Phonegap --no-telemetry error

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, telemetry

Please anybody knows the solution to this problem.

**Error Text:**

```
c:\PhoneGap\SIMPLEGAME>phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android ...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova build android --no-telemetry
```

[image]

Comment: please add some more description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--no-telemetry` is no error. It's a flag.

Your app is build anyway but you do not send usage statistics. See https://cordova.apache.org/privacy/ for detailed information.

See `cordova telemetry help` too.